# Problem filling not only the cell that calls a function, but also the adjacent cells (in Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Assume the following function as a script in Google Sheets:

```
function putData()
{
    return "foo"
}
```

If I now call this function in a cell, it displays "foo":

```
   A           B           C           D
1  =putData()
```

Results in

```
   A           B           C           D
1  foo
```

But what I need is to return values in the 3 cells of the right as well:

```
   A           B           C           D
1  foo        bar         baz         bax
```

Now I could create 4 functions, and call each one in a separate cell.
But I would like to fill the 4 cells with one function call:

```
function putData()
{
    return "foo,bar,baz,bax"
}
```

But this obviously does not work. It is just a string in `A1`. So my question is: how do I need to format the `return` to fill the cell in which the function is called, plus the 3 adjacent cells to the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can return an array of array of strings:

```
function putData()
{
    return [["foo","bar","baz","bax"]];
}
```

and then directly use `=putData()`:

[image]

---

**Solution 2:**

You can return an array of strings:

```
function putData()
{
    return ["foo","bar","baz","bax"];
}
```

and then you can use: `=Transpose(putData())` to get them in a row:

[image]

---

**Solution 3:**

or you can use your current solution:

```
function putData()
{
    return "foo,bar,baz,bax";
}
```

and then split the values `=split(Transpose(putData()),",")`:

[image]